# Can you join dataframes with multiple keys in one of the joining columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to join the following two dataframes.

The first dataframe has multiple keys in one column

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1,2,3], 'key': ['x, y','y', 'z, x']})
>>> df
   col1   key
0     1  x, y
1     2     y
2     3  z, x
```

For each of the key in the first dataframe i have a mapping of sorts in a second dataframe. Like this:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'key': ['x','y','z'], 'value': ["v1,v2, 
v3","v4,v3", "v5"]})

>>> df2
  key      value
0   x  v1,v2, v3
1   y      v4,v3
2   z         v5
```

I would like to end up with all values next to their corresponding keys in one column. Ideally with duplicates removed as in col1 (x and y both have v3).

```
>>> df3
   col1   key           value
0     1  x, y  v1, v2, v3, v4
1     2     y          v4, v3
2     3  z, x  v1, v2, v3, v5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with

```
d=dict(zip(df2.key,df2.value))
df['New']=[','.join([d.get(y) for y in x.split(', ')]) for x in df.key]
```

and now we remove the duplicate

```
df.New=df.New.str.split(',').apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))
df
   col1   key          New
0     1  x, y  v3,v1,v2,v4
1     2     y        v3,v4
2     3  z, x  v5,v3,v1,v2
```

Comment: thanks a bunch. this worked perfectly. just had to fill NAs in the key column of the first df.

Answer (score 3):

Simple for loop

```
for k,v in zip(df2.key, df2.value): 
    df.key = df.key.str.replace(k,v)
```

Outputs

```
    col1    key
0   1       v1,v2, v3, v4,v3
1   2       v4,v3
2   3       v5, v1,v2, v3
```

To remove the duplicates, can `transform`

```
df.key.transform(lambda s: sorted(set([k.strip() for k in s.split(',')])))

    col1    key
0   1       [v1, v2, v3, v4]
1   2       [v3, v4]
2   3       [v1, v2, v3, v5]
```

Answer (score 1):

First we unnest (split) your values to rows:

```
df_new= pd.concat([pd.Series(row['col1'], row['key'].split(','))              
                    for _, row in df.iterrows()]).reset_index().rename({0:'col1', 'index':'key'},axis=1)

print(df_new)
  key  col1
0   x     1
1   y     1
2   y     2
3   z     3
4   x     3
```

Then we merge the values together on the `key` column and `groupby` to aggregate on `col1`:

```
df_final = pd.merge(df_new,df2, on='key',how='left')
df_final = df_final.groupby('col1').agg(', '.join).reset_index()

print(df_final)

   col1   key             value
0     1  x, y  v1,v2, v3, v4,v3
1     2     y             v4,v3
2     3  z, x     v5, v1,v2, v3
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I guess splitting doesn't need a loop: `df[['col1']].join(df['key'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().droplevel(-1).rename('key'))`